# Alignment of long text on image

Tags: html, css

I have a image and long text which should be properly aligned on image. I gave id to image and text then in CSS for text I use position-absolute, top and left. Everything was proper but when I restore browser the text doesn't stay on its original position.When I used other positions for text it doesn't come on Image.

```
<img id="homeimg" src="images/1.jpg" alt="img" width="1280">


                    <p id="text">
                            In 2050, we are projected to have 9 billion on this planet. These people will eat and drink just like we do..
                        requiring a doubling of food production. But food and water security already are the largest challenges for a

                                           thriving global population...and long text

                        </p>
```

Css coding is

```
#text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 45em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 150px;
    top: 600px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    z-index: 100;
}
#homeimg{
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle with an image we can see?

Comment: Images are inline objects. If you want to position element on the image, they must have `position:absolute`, W3school has a great example for this. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Have you tried using your image as a css background-image for the #text element instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a containing element, a div say, you could set the image as the background.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <img src="" /> 
    <p class="text">the text</p> 
</div> 

.container { position relative; width:1280px; height:640px; background:url('image.jpg');background-size:cover;} 
.container .text {position:absolute;etc...}
```

Or if you need to have the inline image, use a containing element with position:relative - any absolute positioned elements inside will be relative to the container.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <img src="" /> 
    <p>text...</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `position:relative` the text will be placed relatively from its **original position** and thus will not stick to the image. One solution to your problem  is to put your text and image in a container, set the container's position to `position:relative` and then use `position:absolute` on your image.

```css
#container{
  position:relative;
}
#text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 45em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 25px;
    left: 150px;
    top: 200px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    z-index: 100;
}
#homeimg{
    width:100%
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<img id="homeimg" src="http://placehold.it/1280x1000" alt="img">
<p id="text">
                            In 2050, we are projected to have 9 billion on this planet. These people will eat and drink just like we do..
                        requiring a doubling of food production. But food and water security already are the largest challenges for a

                                           thriving global population...and long text
</p>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pqdvrwvf/)

By doing so, the text will be position absolutely but relatively from the container.

Comment: didn't work for me. everything get disturb because of using position for container.